# Failed building wheel for tsne Mac

Tags: python, python-wheel, tsne

I'm trying to install tsne package but got error message "Could not build wheels for tsne which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly". I tried updating pip by `usr/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip` as well as updating setuptools wheel by either `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` or just `pip install wheel`. I also tried `pip install p5py`, `pip install PEP517` and `pip install --no-use-pep517 tsne` but none of these works. Any other people experiencing the same problems on Mac when trying to install some packages?

```
Python 3.7.0
pip 21.2.4
wheel 0.37.0
```